# How to flatten object from String to SolrInputDocument

Tags: solr, solrj

I wish to know if it is possible to post JSON/XML strins from SolrJ.

I am currently receiving documents from some messaging service as JSON strings.

One such document is as below:

```
{
  "id":"1","name":"Item 1","price":10,
  "producer":{"id":"10","name":"Prod 1",
    "address": {"id":"100","city":"City 1","zipcode":95000}
  }
}
```

Do I need to convert this string to SolrInputDocument for serving it to Solr?

I am currently using SolrJ and see no API for directly serving a JSON to Solr.

( I see post.jar shipped with Solr is able to post json/xml documents directly to Solr and I would like the same behavior via a SolrJ API )

If there is no such API, how do I convert the string to SolrInputDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to SolrInputDocument. See 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr

But Solr does not allow nested fields. You need to flatten your JSON i.e. keep only scalars, and arrays (or lists) as multi-valued fields only. You may convert it like this:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Item 1",
  "price":10,
  "producer_id":"10",
  "producer_name":"Prod 1",
  "producer_address_id":"100",
  "producer_address_city": "city1",
  "producer_address_zipcode":95000
}
```

or you can also keep the producer address in a multi-valued field like this:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Item 1",
  "price":10,
  "producer_id":"10",
  "producer_name":"Prod 1",
  "producer_address":["100", "city1", "95000"]
}
```

Which one you should choose depends on your query requirements.

Comment: Thanks @arun. I cannot add POJO directly because I am getting the json string (corresponding to a POJO) from a messaging service.  
  
To convert that json string back to POJO would require me to have the classes loaded in my application interacting with messaging service which would be cumbersome.  
  
So I guess, I would have to manually flatten my josn strings.  
Not sure how schema.xml will be managed then.    
Do you know of any library/tool that can do that for me ?  
  
Also, please suggest if it is OK to use "." instead of "_" for flattening the json?

Comment: schema.xml needs to be designed according to your search requirements. I am not sure if any tools exist to auto-generate schema for you, but even if they exist, you need to decide on your search requirements. Using `.` instead of `_` for word separator should be fine for the field names.

Comment: Solr does allow nested fields.

Comment: @rjurney This was answered in 2013 :-). Feel free to add your own answer below.